# MySQL Access Denied (CentOS)

Tags: centos, mysql

I have installed fresh MySQL server on CentOS, and started the MySQL server service with command.

```
 # /sbin/service mysqld start
```

I checked the service and it is running.

Currently I am logged in as `root@localhost`. I want to changed the password for `root`. For this I have issued the command:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Once I issued this command, system is asked for password, I tried to just hit "enter". This does not work. Also, tried my Linux root password that also does not work.

When I tried to hit enter I am getting:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password : NO)
```

When I tried with Linux box local root password I am getting:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password : YES)
```

Other than local machine `root` password, it did not ask me for any password during installation time. What I am missing here? What should I do to login from the mysql-workbench? Thanks.

Comment: The password is probably the word `root`.

Answer (score 1):

edit `/etc/my.cnf` and add:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

then restart MySQL service and try to login

```
mysql
```

also you can check [official manual]:

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a root password stetup there normally you should run `mysql_secure_installation` as root that will prompt you for mysql root password and there just hit enter.

In your case it looks like there is a root password setup you can change it by using

`sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --skip-grant-tables`

This will let you start mysql and you can `mysql -u root` into mysql after  that is matter of updating root password.

```
mysql> use mysql; 
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("yournewrootpasshere") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

`--skip-grant-tables` option is the key using that it will not prompt for a password.

After this if you restart mysql normally it will come up and you can even run `mysql_secure_installation` again with you new root pass if you want.

Since this is a fresh install you can also remove mysql package and reinstall it as well. Remember to remove database as well.

Comment: for this I tried to hit enter and that did not work